# Is there a way to prevent Apache CloseableHttpClient from throwing HttpResponseException?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents, web-api-testing

I'm using Apache HttpComponents (4.5.11) to test web APIs.

For negative testing (e.g. sending a bad request), I also want to check the response body but `CloseableHttpClient` throws `HttpResponseException` with the response's status code instead of returning the actual response.
Is there a way to prevent this or should I just switch to another library (e.g. RestAssured)?

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request)) {
     ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
     String body = handler.handleResponse(response);
     //Deserialize and perform response assertions..
} catch(HttpResponseException e){
    //Exception is caught here..
}
```

pom.xml dependency:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure understand the problem. There is nothing stopping you from getting the status code and reading the response content directly from the response object.

```
try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
     CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request)) {
    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        try (InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent()) {
            // Do something useful with the response
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: handler.handleResponse(response);
this statement was the one throwing the exception. I removed it and handled the response myself.
Thanks for your help @ok2c